# Como usar macros no VS2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Sei usar macros apenas no NetBeans conforme o manual https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/macro-keywords_pt_BR.html.

Porém queria saber como faço para usar macros no vs2008?
Quero definir um macro e uma tecla de atalho para ele.

ex: um macro que escreva no editor "blababla"[nova linha] "blablabla".

Comment: Eu utilizo o bom e velho Notepadd++, você quer fazer macros com alguma função específica do Visual Studio ?

Comment: gostaria de usar as funções básicas como quebra de linha, retorno do cursor, assim como no netBens ex: caret-begin-line faz com que o cursor retorne no começo da linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nos links abaixo você encontra tutoriais para gravar macros no Visual Studio:

[How to: Record Macros](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/7kyhdt1z%28v=vs.90%29)

[Creating and Using a Macro](https://web.archive.org/web/20140621112725/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zainnab/archive/2010/12/02/creating-and-using-a-macro-vstipenv0055.aspx)

[Create a Shortcut Key for a Macro](https://web.archive.org/web/20150628163804/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zainnab/archive/2010/08/07/create-a-shortcut-key-for-a-macro-vstiptool0066.aspx)